# Hibernate always running redundant query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, one-to-one

I've an OneToOne relationship in my data model, and hibernate is ALWAYS querying both entities in order to generate the resultset.

This is the data model

```
@Entity
public class C1 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false, targetEntity = C2.class)
    private C2 c2;

    //... other stuff
}


@Entity
public class C2 extends OtherClassOutOfDomain {

   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "c2")
    private C1 c1;

    //... other stuff
}
```

Hibernate generate my schema as two tables and the C1 table has a foreign key to C2, what is perfect to me as i will be more often using the C1.

BUT

Everytime I query for C1 hibernate generate 1 query joining both entities data per row, and generate N queries for every row in the result of first (EVEN BEFORE I ACCESS THE RESULT SET)

example

```
Hibernate (just one): 
    select
        this_.id as id1_2_1_,
        this_.c2_id as authDat22_2_1_,
        this_.bio as bio2_2_1_,
        this_.blocked as blocked3_2_1_,
        this_.commentsAmount as comments4_2_1_,
        this_.confirmed as confirme5_2_1_,
        this_.deleted as deleted6_2_1_,
        c22_.id as id1_0_0_,
        c22_.adid as adid2_0_0_,
    from
        c1 this_ 
    inner join
        c2 c22_
            on this_.authData_id=c22_.id

Hibernate (N times as the size of previous query): 
    select
        this_.id as id1_2_1_,
        this_.c2_id as authDat22_2_1_,
        this_.bio as bio2_2_1_,
        this_.blocked as blocked3_2_1_,
        this_.commentsAmount as comments4_2_1_,
        this_.confirmed as confirme5_2_1_,
        this_.deleted as deleted6_2_1_,
        c22_.id as id1_0_0_,
        c22_.adid as adid2_0_0_,
    from
        c1 this_ 
    inner join
        c2 c22_
            on this_.authData_id=c22_.id
    where
            this_.authData_id=?
.....repeat
.....repeat
.....repeat
```

the result of repeated queries is cointained in the row of first big query... is there any way to avoid these unecessary requests? i tried set as lazy, but it didn´t work

the code i'm running to get this behavior is simple

```
HibernateUtils.createNewSession().createCriteria(C1.class).list();
```

I'm not even accessing the result before it triggers the nested queries

I'm using hibernate 5.10 e mysql 5.7.17

Comment: optional = false ? Please try with true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution but I didn't completely understood why.

As mapping OneToOne relationship with JPA hibernate will put the foreign key on the entity which has the "targetEntity" attribute (THE ENTITY WITH THE ATTRIBUTE NO THE ENTITY SETTED IN ATRIBUTE VALUE)

While querying by an entity which has a foreign key in its structure hibernate will automatically query for the nested entities (I don't know the reason)

To solve my previous related problem, I just needed to change the annotation to

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false, mappedBy= "c1")
private C2 c2; 

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = C1.class) 
private C1 c1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep these two things in your mind.

The default fetch strategy of OneToOne is EAGER.

LAZY can only work on a OneToOne association if the association is non-nullable.

Your problem is similar to N+1 Selects Problem

Resolve N+1 SELECTs problem:

**HQL fetch join**

Either

from 
   C1 c1
 left join fetch 
    c1.c2

or

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false, mappedBy= "c1")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) 
private C2 c2;
```

and in second class

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "c2")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) 
private C1 c1;
```